# Create Blank two dimensional array with key and push values in it

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the example of my sample array. I want to achieve array like this,

```
        var myObj = { 
            PlannedStartDate: { value: '123', mandatory: 'yes' }, 
            PlannedEndDate: { value: '456', mandatory: 'no' }, 
            Days: { value: '123', mandatory: 'yes' } 
        };
```

**OutPut-1** :-

[image]

I want to achieve above array with `push()` method or any other process. 
So, For that I tried like this,

```
var post_outage_array = [];
post_outage_array.push({"PlannedStartDate" : '123'});
console.log(post_outage_array);
```

But It gives me below result,

[image]

I have even Tried with `post_outage_array['0']['PlannedStartDate'] = '123';`.

So, I my goal is to first declare blank two dimensional array and push values with key and want to achieve output like above image. (OutPut-1)

Edit :- As per the gurvinder372's suggestion.

```
    var post_outage_array = {};
    post_outage_array["PlannedStartDate"]["value"] = '123';
    post_outage_array["PlannedStartDate"]["mandatory"] = 'yes';
```

When I tried to do it in that manner. I got the following error.

```
index.php:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
```

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between what you have and what you want.

Comment: Expected output is an Object

Comment: @31piy. I want to change 0 to "PlannedStartDate" inshort `key` name.

Comment: `var post_outage_array = {};
post_outage_array["PlannedStartDate"] = '123';`

Comment: thats not possible

Comment: Your expected output is not an array. So why are you creating one?

Comment: @H77. Ok got you so I need to change `var post_outage_array = {} ` Right ? But how Can I push it for two dimensional array.

Comment: No idea what you mean. Is what @gurvinder372 suggested the solution you are after?

Comment: @h77. Yes. his suggestion works for me. I need exactly the same output which gurvinder372 suggest. Please check I have edited my question with error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're not after an array, but are looking to add the properties to an object dynamically (possibly in a loop?).

Is this what you're after?

```js
// method 1

var post_outage = {};
post_outage["PlannedStartDate"] = {};
post_outage["PlannedStartDate"]["value"] = '123';
post_outage["PlannedStartDate"]["mandatory"] = 'yes';

console.log(post_outage);

// method 2
var post_outage = {};
post_outage["PlannedStartDate"] = {
  value: "123",
  mandatory: "yes"
};

console.log(post_outage);
```

Comment: Oh got you man.Thank you it's working.I need to again initialize `post_outage["PlannedStartDate"] = {};` It's working.

Answer (score 1):

You are NOT expecting an array but instead you ARE expecting an object formed of arrays.

to achieve that, defined three array variables like:

```
var Days             = [] ;
var plannedEndDate   = [] ;
var plannedStartDate = [] ;
```

then push values to each using the `push` method, and then:

```
var finalObject = {} ;
finalObject = {
        Days             : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Days            )) ,
        plannedEndDate   : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(plannedEndDate  )) ,
        plannedStartDate : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(plannedStartDate))  } ;
```